# Mysql remove nulls from case

Tags: mysql

[image]

how do i show one row per id when i run the query it staggers accross the screen

```
SELECT empid,
       ( CASE
           WHEN begin_date = '2020-03-13'
                AND amount THEN amount
         END ) '3/13/2020',
       ( CASE
           WHEN begin_date = '2020-03-27' THEN amount
         END ) '3/27/2020',
       ( CASE
           WHEN begin_date = '2020-04-10' THEN amount
         END ) '4/10/2020',
       ( CASE
           WHEN begin_date = '2020-04-24' THEN amount
         END ) '4/24/2020',
       ( CASE
           WHEN begin_date = '2020-05-08' THEN amount
         END ) '5/08/2020',
       ( CASE
           WHEN begin_date = '2020-05-22' THEN amount
         END ) '5/22/2020',
       ( CASE
           WHEN begin_date = '2020-06-05' THEN amount
         END ) '6/05/2020',
       ( CASE
           WHEN begin_date = '2020-06-19' THEN amount
         END ) '6/19/2020',
       ( CASE
           WHEN begin_date = '2020-07-03' THEN amount
         END ) '7/03/2020',
       ( CASE
           WHEN begin_date = '2020-07-17' THEN amount
         END ) '7/17/2020',
       ( CASE
           WHEN begin_date = '2020-07-31' THEN amount
         END ) '7/31/2020',
       ( CASE
           WHEN begin_date = '2020-08-14' THEN amount
         END ) '8/14/2020',
       ( CASE
           WHEN begin_date = '2020-08-28' THEN amount
         END ) '8/28/2020',
       ( CASE
           WHEN begin_date = '2020-09-11' THEN amount
         END ) '9/11/2020',
       ( CASE
           WHEN begin_date = '2020-09-25' THEN amount
         END ) '9/25/2020',
       ( CASE
           WHEN begin_date = '2020-10-09' THEN amount
         END ) '10/09/2020',
       ( CASE
           WHEN begin_date = '2020-10-23' THEN amount
         END ) '10/23/2020',
       ( CASE
           WHEN begin_date = '2020-11-06' THEN amount
         END ) '11/06/2020',
       ( CASE
           WHEN begin_date = '2020-11-20' THEN amount
         END ) '11/20/2020',
       ( CASE
           WHEN begin_date = '2020-12-04' THEN amount
         END ) '12/04/2020',
       ( CASE
           WHEN begin_date = '2020-12-18' THEN amount
         END ) '12/18/2020',
       ( CASE
           WHEN begin_date = '2020-12-31' THEN amount
         END ) '12/31/2020'
FROM   new_table
WHERE  amount > 0
```

Comment: THEN amount ELSE '' END ?

Comment: the null goes away but i need all the info on one row for each id

Comment: this info should be in your question and not in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one row per `empid`, you need to use `sum` and `group by`.  Also, we have to be careful about summing `NULL` since `NULL` plus anything is always `NULL`, so we can use an `else` on the case statement to avoid that issue.

I'm assuming amount is `nullable` in your table, if that's not the case then you don't need the extra "`AND amount is NOT NULL`" condition.

Here's the idea:

```
SELECT empid,
       ( SUM(
           CASE
             WHEN begin_date = '2020-03-13'
                AND amount IS NOT NULL THEN amount
             ELSE 0
           END) ) '3/13/2020',
       .
       .
       .
FROM   new_table
WHERE  amount > 0
GROUP BY empid
```

Comment: Why not use COALESCE instead of the case?

Comment: @Chris Strickland - You still have to test the begin_date value, so I think you still need to use CASE here.

Comment: the sum seems to adding i just need the amount to stay the same per id

Comment: @user1061123 - If there is more than one value per date for a given empid, then you must either sum those values or you could also take a max instead of a sum.  But if you want one row for each empid, then you have to group the values in some way (e.g. using sum, max, avg, etc.)

Comment: @dcp Couldn't you also use [ANY_VALUE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value)?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear.  Yes, the case, although I wish mySQL had better pivot support.  I meant CASE WHEN begin_date = 'xxxx' THEN COALESCE(amount, 0) ELSE 0 END seems terser to me

Comment: @kmoser - I think that would work as well although I have not used that function

Comment: @Chris Strickland - Got it, thanks